# Frege: Begriffsschrift, Identity of Content explanation?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, math-history

On Page 21 Section 8 of the English translation, there is lengthy geometric explanation.  I'm having difficulty picturing what is being explained due to wording and perhaps loss during translation.

Can anyone help explain the geometric circle example that is given and it's relation to $(A \equiv B)$?  I'm uncertain if point B should be the center of the circle or on the circumference.

Also, if $\vdash (A \implies X) \land (B \implies Z)$ were defined how would $\equiv$ identity of content resolve?

[image]

Geometric Example:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: At that stage of development of Frege's logic the sumbol $\equiv$ is ambiguous between material equivalence (the propositional connective bi-conditional) and equality between terms.

Comment: The example tries to elucidate the idea that the symbol express not the identity between the two expressions $A$ and $B$ (meaning : the two strings of symbols) but *identity of content*, i.e. identity between the (conceptual) content expressed by the two expression. In a nutshell : "Napoleon" and "the Emperor of France" are two different expression denoting the same individual.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So $\equiv$ is equivalent to $\iff$ per your comment.  I'm still trying to figure out the geometric example he provides. Thanks

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Maybe I'm confused.  Can the identity of content be another concept expression denoted with a string of more signs?

Comment: "Is $\equiv$ equiv to $\leftrightarrow$ ?" Yes and no; yes when used beyween formulas; no when used between terms, in which case moder logic uses *equality* : $=$. Frege conflates the twos **also** because he treats (in a certain sense) sentences as *names*: a sentenbce denotes a truth value.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA now I think I'm experiencing confusing grammatical issues.  Is '$A \implies B \implies C$ a formula?  Does it contain 3 terms $A, B, C$?  How does a sentence differ?  I do not think Frege uses these grammatical names... Thanks

Comment: I'll try to simplify it; in the context of *propositional calculus*, Frege's symbol $\equiv$ **is** the bi-conditional : $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the "geometric example" $A$ and $B$ are names of points, i.e. terms. This means, that the example is relative to the second usage of $\equiv$ by Frege: that of *equality* between terms. Compare with formula (52) at page 50, Sect.20 (substitutivy of equals) that (in modern terms) is : $\vdash (c=d) \to (f(c) \to f(d))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's the geometric example illustrated:

> Assume that on the circumference of a circle there is a fixed point $A$ about which a ray revolves.  When this ray passes through the center of the circle, we call the other point at which it intersects the circle the point *B* associated with this position of the ray.

[image]

Now imagine that the ray “revolves around $A$”.  That is, it changes direction while still passing through $A$:

[image: ![enter image description here]

> The point of intersection, other than $A$, of the ray and the circumference, will then be called the point $B$ associated with the position of the ray at any time; this point is such that continuous variations of its position must always correspond to continuous variations in the position of the ray.

So, as the ray turns continuously, point $B$ moves continuously along the circumference of the circle.

> We can now ask: what point is associated with the position of the ray when it is perpendicular to the diameter?

[image]

> The answer will be: the point $A$.

(This is geometrically a little bit confused, but let's agree to understand the geometry the way Frege asks us to: even when the ray is perpendicular to the diameter of the circle, there are still two intersections, one defined by $A$ and the other defined by its “other” intersection with the circumference. It just so happens that the two intersections are in the same place.)

---

Now here's why Frege introduces this example. As mathematics has evolved, so has our understanding of the “=” symbol.  It is much more philosophically complex than it appears.  What do we actually mean when we say that $$2+2=4?$$  The accepted explanation prior to Frege was that the two sides are just names for the same entity, analogous to the way one would write “Mark Twain is Samuel Clemens”: they are two names for the same individual, and the “=” sign means that the two entities are the same.

Frege wants us to understand that this account is insufficient.  If “$2+2”$ and “$4$” are simply different names for the same object, and if “=” simply means that the objects are the same, then the meaning of “2+2=4” should be the same as the meaning of “4=4”.  Which, of course it isn't.  To consider a more extreme example, take Euler's famous formula $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x.$$  If the left and right sides are simply names for the same thing, why is this formula more interesting than the less-famous formula “$e^{ix} = e^{ix}$”?  Why do we think that “Mark Twain is Samuel Clemens” is more interesting than “Mark Twain is Mark Twain”, if both assertions mean exactly the same thing?

In Frege's example, we have fixed point $A$ and varying point $B$.  When the ray is perpendicular to the diameter, $A=B$.  Are $A$ and $B$ simply names for the same point?

**Frege wants to distinguish two kinds of meaning**, which he calls “sense” (*Sinn*) and “reference” (*Bedeutung*).  In Frege's view, “$2+2=4$” has content different from “$4=4$” because the *sense* of “2+2” is different from the sense of “4”, even though the thing to which they refer (the number four) is the same in both cases.

Similarly, at a particular moment, “the fixed point $A$” and “The other intersection of the ray with the circumference” may happen to *refer* to the same point, but their *sense* is still quite different.

> From this it follows that the existence of different names for the same content is not always merely an irrelevant question of form…

“2+2”, says Frege, is not merely a different way of writing “4”.

> rather, that there are such names is the very heart of the matter if each is associated with a different way of determining the content.

The sense of “2+2” is the result of an arithmetic addition process.  The sense of “4” is not.  They are *different ways of determining the content*. To assert that “2+2=4” is to assert that these two different ways of determining content do determine the same thing, in this case the number four.

---

Now what does Frege want us to understand by  $\vdash A\equiv B$?  There the language is a little mixed.  I take $A$ and $B$ to be names for signs.  For example, $A$ might be the sign “2+2” and $B$ might be “4”. (Or $A$ might be “the fixed point $A$” and B might be “the other intersection of the ray with the circumference when the ray is perpendicular to the diameter”.)  Then by $$2+2\equiv 4$$ Frege means that the signs “$2+2$” and “$4$” *refer to* the same object.  And $$\vdash 2+2\equiv 4$$ means that we judge or assert that this is actually the case.

Comment: Thanks the geometric explanation makes sense.  I would argue that 2 + 2 and 4 are different objects until the + function is applied.  Do you know if the three lines in the \equiv function symbol has any meaning?  For instance = may imply two equal length lines... Thanks!